# rvm issue with ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I have a problem with my ruby version, rails and rvm.
when I go into my rails project directory, and run  `bundle install`, I get a message saying:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0


Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system Rubygems.
You can cancel this installation and run:

    bundle install --path vendor/bundle

to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your password
and install the bundled gems to Rubygems using sudo.

Password:
```

I kill this job, and then run 
    `rvm info`
run the 
    `bundle install` 
again, and everything is working fine.

I get different error depending on what command I'm running, but running rvm info after always solves the problem.

any idea?

Mike

Comment: This is strange. IME, rvm info just tells you about the various platform information. Do you have .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset files in your project folder?

Comment: I do for some projects and don't for others. I do find it really weird too.